# Can't resolve all parameters for AuthGuard: In my AuthGuard service

Tags: angular, routes, angular5, auth-guard

I have a code for AuthGuard.service.ts as follows.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { userLoginService } from './userLoginService';
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private service: userLoginService) { }
    canActivate() {
        if (this.service.IsloggedIn()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            window.alert(' You are not logged in.Please LogIn ');
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

In userLoginService.ts, I have code as follows

```
export class userLoginService {
    constructor() {}
    IsloggedIn(): boolean {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am injecting this AuthGuard.service.ts in  my route as follows. And I have also provided this service name in providers of NgModule.

```
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component: HomePageComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'CartItems', component: CartItemsComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [ AuthGuard ]},
    ];
@NgModule({
.
.
.
 providers: [UserInfoService , AuthGuard],
.
.
.
```

Now when executing this code I am getting an error as follows.

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AuthGuard: (?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:466)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:15547)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:15382)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (compiler.js:15362)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (compiler.js:15722)
    at eval (compiler.js:15633)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.js:15593)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15161)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:33542)
```

Would you please let me know where I have committed a mistake.

Comment: And where do you provide the `UserLoginService`? Is it even `@Injectable`?

Comment: yes I made it injectable.

Comment: can you add the entire file for the routes (with imports) @roopteja

Comment: But you aren't actually *showing that*, or its inclusion in the module. Give a [mcve].

Comment: I have not given the import statement correctly. It is working fine now. Sorry for the disturbance. And Thank You for the help.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry for the disturbance. It is my bad. Thank You for the help. I will make sure that I will not do like this again.

Answer (score 32):

I see you import Injectable but you never use it !!

In your AuthGuard.service.ts. you should add : `@Injectable()` above your class as like :

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AuthGuard: (?).
>           at syntaxError (compiler.js:431)
>           at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata ..............

I'm facing this problem too long and just solve this error by following.

Please add those two line in your 'app.component.ts' and your problem will be solved.

```js
    import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

    import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I moved guard file to another directory. Re ng serve solved my problem.